# How can I select 2 items each in an array making sure every set is outputed

Tags: php, laravel

Lets say I have an array of numbers: `[1,2,3]`.

How can I loop through this `array` to create an array of possible [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

I'm expecting outputs like:
`[1,2]`, `[1,3]`, `[2,1]`, `[2,3]`, `[3,1]`, `[3,2]`.

Comment: Hint: loop in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Simple nested loops required for the same input array

Do the following:

```
$input = array(1,2,3);

$output = array();

// to get all possible permutations
// for first value in the permutation, loop over all array values
foreach ($input as $value1) {

    // for second value in the permutation, loop again similarly
    foreach ($input as $value2) {

        if ($value1 !== $value2)  // dont consider same values
            $output[] = array($value1, $value2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoters do explain! What is wrong with the code. Ready to learn

Comment: I'm very confused why both our answers were downvoted

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote is because this code produces the undesired values `[1, 1]`, `[2, 2]`, etc.

Comment: `$output` is not exactly what he expected.

Comment: Yes, now its ok...Downvote undo..by the way you missed a `)`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya , It worked. But as Alex Howansky said, I do not want to have [1, 1], [2, 2] and [3, 3] in the result. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @OlaideBolanle check the updated answer. It should work for you now. Thanks. Do consider marking it as accepted answer.

Comment: @OlaideBolanle happy to help :)

Comment: What if I do not want [1,2] and [2,1] both returned?

Comment: @OlaideBolanle then if condition inside the for loop needs to be custom changed. But is there a logic behind your requirements ? Maybe a generalized solution can be formulated

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question correctly, you want to have an array containing X amount of integers and get every possible combination of two distinct integers from that array?

This can be done with two for loops, one to loop through each of your array's elements, and another that combines that element with every other element.

```
for(int $x = 0; $x < count($arr1); $x++) {
    for(int $y = 0; $y < count($arr1); $y++) {
        if ($x == $y || $arr1[$x] == $arr1[$y]) {
            continue;
        } else {
            array_push($output, [$arr1[$x], $arr1[$y]]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example I assumed you don't want repeating numbers.  So I did a loop with an inner loop and compared the numbers before adding to the print Array!  My first stackoverflow submissions so I'd love some feedback!

```
$arrayToParse = [1, 2, 3];
$arrayToPrint = [];

foreach($arrayToParse as $num1){
    foreach($arrayToParse as $num2){
        if($num1 != $num2){
            array_push($arrayToPrint, [$num1, $num2]);
        }
    }
}

print_r($arrayToPrint);

// OUTPUT
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```